# Devise unpermitted params error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I setup Devise in my rails application. I also setup a devise parameter sanitizer in my application controller. But when I sign up using the custom parameters I get a 'unpermitted parameter error' in my rails local server log. The weird issue is that this was working at one time.. and now it seems to be broken. I have looked through my Devise configuration and the Documentation and I set up the the Sanitizer properly.

**Application_Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  include Pundit
  include Redcarpet
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :lastname, :username) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :firstname, :lastname, :username) }
  end
end
```

**Rails Server Log:**

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-05 16:02:57 -0700
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PhMqJOEO7fLyUJiWjHcnu+wyB0EQwDeCV9m6XsT5kZ/IyVZ9ZUpwLc26sNbRZleh6xz7V90bvA+yqUBkDkhMmA==", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"Austin", "lastname"=>"Thesing", "username"=>"austinthesing", "email"=>"me@me.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: firstname, lastname, username
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'austin@designxdevelop.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "role", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["email", "me@me.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$11$KQLR6rLh0qrMfzX90FToP.Yo.i0wmfPkvvw7JOKQIn4smtzk9HJkm"], ["role", 0], ["created_at", "2016-06-05 23:02:57.825074"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-05 23:02:57.825074"], ["confirmation_token", "HMkLUzBwoXB7NZxvYJCA"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2016-06-05 23:02:57.825333"]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (4.9ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `before_action` callback to call the `configure_permitted_parameters` method in your Application Controller if the controller is a devise controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :firstname, :lastname, :username) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :firstname, :lastname, :username) }      end
end
```

Also, see that the method is protected

Read more about Devise strong parameters [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

Comment: @elmagnifico Thank you!! That before_action call back is basically saying: If the devise_controller run this method first.. Right? Thanks again.

Comment: Exactly! The method will only be called if the controller in action is a devise controller.  You are welcome :)